# DATALENGTH() works on literals but doesn't work on variables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

The `select datalength(cast('12345' as nvarchar))` query returns 10 (this is OK), but

```
declare @string as nvarchar
set @string = cast('12345' as nvarchar)
select datalength(@string)
```

returns 2 instead of 10. Why? How can I use DATALENGHT() for determining the datalength of a string stored in a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always specify the length `n` of character data.  eg

```
declare @string as nvarchar(30)
set @string = cast('12345' as nvarchar(30))
select datalength(@string)
```

The behavior if you don't is described in the docs:

> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration
>   statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified with the
>   CAST function, the default length is 30.

[nchar and nvarchar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)